# Strange diagonal line in Google Visualization API

Tags: google-visualization

Sometimes I get a strange diagonal line in my Google Line Chart. Please see below the blue Volume chart.

It is has that "closing" line from the first to the last value.

Any idea how this comes?

[image: strange diagonal line]

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date')
data.addColumn('number', 'Volume')
data.addColumn('number', 'Connected')
for tracking in trackings
    if(tracking.createdAt instanceof Date && tracking.volume? && typeof tracking.volume is "number")
        connected = if(tracking.connected? && tracking.connected) then 10000 else -10000
        data.addRow([tracking.createdAt, tracking.volume, connected])
options = {
    title: 'Sensor Values'
    legend:
        position: 'bottom'
    hAxis:
        minValue: from
        maxValue: to
    curveType: 'function'
}
chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('volumeChart'))
chart.draw(data, options)
```

Comment: I check a lot of stuff. I added some code above.

Comment: `console.log(tracking.createdAt)` for each row would be needed to verify the data -- if you add `interpolateNulls: true` to your options, does the line look normal?

Comment: I check for all values beeing not null. interpolateNulls: true also changes nothing.

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat. I found the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue disappears when you sort the data by date.

It appeared when I had ca. more than 200 unsorted data points on the graph.

In Meteor / MongoDB this worked for me:

```
data = SensorTracking.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}}).fetch()
```

Answer (score 1):

For us the problem was that we accidentally added our dataset twice to the graph. Adding it only once did the trick ;)